# How to get a list of directories and/or files on a remote server using libcurl? (generally how to send a CLI command using libcurl)

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I'm trying to write a code that sends files onto a remote server every day, in a directory with the date of that day, and compresses the contents of directories every week. (7 directories should be compressed per week in a single file.)

e.g. Following list includes 7 directories for 7 days. After `2023-11-16` all directories should be compressed in a single file.

```
2023-11-10/ # This directory includes files from 2023-11-10

2023-11-11/

2023-11-12/

.

.

.

2023-11-16/
```

How can I do that using libcurl?

P.S. FTP and SSH are both available (running) on the remote machine

Thanks

Comment: How does the remote machine expose the parent directory /  mount point ?

Comment: FTP and SSH are both available on the remote machine.

Comment: Probably easiest to do it using libssh2. You can pretty much just make a connection, then execute commands, about like you would with a manually created ssh connection.

Comment: I'd use rsync to copy files and have a weekly cron job on the remote machine to do the compression. Just a few lines of shell for both parts.

Comment: You could use [`libcurl`](https://curl.se/libcurl/) for this.  But a combination of `rsync`/`cron` and `logrotate` should turn this into a pretty trivial thing to implement.

Comment: @erik258 I said that in the question. I just wanna to know how I can send CLI commands to a remote server using libcurl.

Comment: Well, what have you tried thus far?  I see 2 programming languages mentioned - C and C++.   Remove the extra, leaving only the tag of the language you're actually using, and include a minimal representation of what you've tried so far, intended result, and actual behavior.